# discord bot AFK command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm trying to make an AFK command but the nickname doesn't want to work. Here's my code.

```py
@Client.command(name="AFK")
async def afk(context):
    name = context.author.display_name
    author = context.author
    guild = context.guild
    AFKrole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="AFK")
    if not AFKrole:
        AFKrole = await guild.create_role(name="AFK")
    await context.member.edit(nick=f"[AFK]{name}")
    await author.add_roles(AFKrole)
    await context.send(f"I have added {author} to AFK.")
```

Comment: Well it is because bot has no permission to change nick of guild owner. You have to create alternative account and try this command on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
await ctx.author.edit(nick=f'[AFK]{name}') #ctx = context, but you can change it to context
```

or try giving it the manage_nicknames permission.
[click here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) <- The docs on the edit function

Comment: Sorry it not detailed enough as you want it to me (maybe)